# Once opened, isn't a volume encrypted using cryptsetup readable by all users?

Tags: linux, security, disk-encryption, luks

A volume is encrypted using cryptsetup. Once `cryptsetup open ...` has been executed, isn't the mapped device then readable by all users on the host? If they know the file system, they can trivially extract contents of all the files.

Googling around, I couldn't figure out why this isn't regarded a problem.

Comment: `isn't the mapped device then readable by all users on the host` - if they are not root and the permissions are locked down, then maybe not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the device node created by the device mapper (`/dev/mapper/...`) is not world-readable. In `/dev/mapper` we see:

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root       7 27. Jan 11:01 remote-backup -> ../dm-0
```

pointing to (note that the permissions of the node pointed to, not the permissions of the symlink above are relevant):

```
brw-rw----. 1 root disk  253, 0 27. Jan 11:01 ../dm-0
```

Thus, a user would either need to be in the `disk` group or be root to access the raw contents of the mapped device. An untrusted user should of course never have these privilegues, otherwise, not only reading, but also destruction of data would be possible.

(The above output is on a normally configured Fedora. Your mileage may vary on different systems)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is true - subject to the usual filesystem access restrictions of course.

As to why this is not regarded as a problem:

This depends on the [threat model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threat_model) - that is, on the attacks and attackers you worry about. Generally, encryption of filesystems is only useful as protection from physical attacks against the hardware (e.g. stealing it).

If an attacker has network access while the system is running, or even an account on the system, filesystem encryption will not help. However, in that case the usual filesystem permissions do help - which nicely shows how different security measures complement each other.

This is well-known. For example, Ubuntu's "Encrypted Filesystem Howto" [warns](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystemHowto#Panaceas_and_black_boxes):

> Panaceas and black boxes
>
> Don't forget this is NOT a perfect system. It is still vulnerable to
>   attack by a variety of ways, the most obvious being an attack while
>   online. If you are able to access your encrypted data then anyone else
>   who gets into the system will be as well. [...]